# How to read CSV file as a tuple dictionary with keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I want to read a csv file and save keys with multiple values as a tuple in my program. The CSV file has data for some countries representing their CO2 emission from 1997 to 2010. I want the country name to be the key and the emission rates to be values stored in a tuple. Below is an example of the CSV file and what I want.

CSV File:

```
 Afgahnistan, value1,value2,value3,value4,....,value_n
 Algeria, value1,value2,.....,value_n
 nth country, value1, value2,....,value_n
```

Desired dictionary:

```
myDict = {
      "Afghanistan": (value1, value 2,.....,value_n),
      "Algeria": (value1, value 2,.....,value_n),
      .
      .
      .
      "nth country": (value1, value 2,.....,value_n)
      }
```

The code I have developed is shown below:

```
import csv
with open('Book1.csv') as f:
    data=[tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(f)]

print(data)
```

However, the output is a bit changed. I am currently getting the following output:

```
data = [('Afghanistan', 'value1', value2,...,'value_n'), ('Algeria', 'value1', value2,...,'value_n'),....,('nth country', 'value1', value2,...,'value_n')]
```

Can you please let me know of the changes I need to make in the code to achieve the desired outcome?

Answer (score 3):

If using Python 3+ you can use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) to separate the keys from the values in each line then add each item to a dictionary.

```
import csv
d = {}
with open('Book1.csv') as f:
    for key, *values in csv.reader(f):
        d[key] = tuple(map(float, values))
```

Comment: Save a line of unpacking by doing it in the `for` loop itself: `for key, *values in csv.reader(f):`

Comment: This code currently reads the values as string, how can I convert them to integer?

Comment: Sorry for asking such a foolish question, have identified how to convert the values into integer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv("Book1.csv")
d = dict()
for x in a.columns:
    d[x] = tuple(a[x].values)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I tried the solution of @wwii and it already worked :-) Thanks Anyways.